# How to invert a full matrix?

Tags: r

I have a matrix

```
            X1         X2        X3        X4        X5        X6           G1            G2
X1            5         0         0         0         0         0            5            0 
X2            0         5         0         0         0         0            5            0
X3            0         0         5         0         0         0            5            0
X4            0         0         0         5         0         0            0            5
X5            0         0         0         0         5         0            0            5  
X6            0         0         0         0         0         5            0            5  
G1            5         5         5         0         0         0           15            0  
G2            0         0         0         5         5         5            0           15
```

There are dependence lineal in the two last rows and columns, I try to delete one row and one column (for example G1), but the resulting matrix still has a linear dependence, so I can't invert the matrix.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: And can you make a smaller example, maybe? I guess not all the rows are needed.

Comment: Seems, the determinant of your matrix is 0 - so, there is no inverse.

Answer (score 6):

The symmetric matrix `m`, shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, is singular which is implied by its having at least one zero eigenvalue (in fact, it has two):

```
eigen(m)$values
## [1]  2.000000e+01  2.000000e+01  5.000000e+00  5.000000e+00  5.000000e+00
## [6]  5.000000e+00 -4.671248e-24 -4.671248e-24
```

Thus, it cannot be inverted; however, you can take the [Moore Penrose generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) using [ginv](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/ginv.html) from the MASS package. A generalized inverse does satisfy the relation shown in the last line of code below. Note that the MASS package comes with R so you don't need to install it.

```
library(MASS)

gm <- ginv(m)
all.equal(m %*% gm %*% m, m)
## [1] TRUE
```

Note that there are two linear dependencies owing to the two zero eigenvalues. By inspection we note that the sum of the first 3 rows of `m` equals the 7th row and the sum of the 4th through 6th rows equals the 8th row so dropping rows 7 and 8 and the corresponding columns due to symmetry we see that the upper left 6x6 submatrix is invertible:

```
solve(m[-(7:8), -(7:8)])
```

Alternately we can find constraints by inspection of the eigenvectors of `m`.

### Note

```
Lines <- "X1         X2        X3        X4        X5        X6           G1            G2
X1            5         0         0         0         0         0            5            0 
X2            0         5         0         0         0         0            5            0
X3            0         0         5         0         0         0            5            0
X4            0         0         0         5         0         0            0            5
X5            0         0         0         0         5         0            0            5  
X6            0         0         0         0         0         5            0            5  
G1            5         5         5         0         0         0           15            0  
G2            0         0         0         5         5         5            0           15"
m <- as.matrix(read.table(text = Lines))
```

Comment: or similarly `pinv(m)` but needs to install package `pracma` :)